Hostlistener is not working in firefox but working in chrome and edge
Inside hostlistener I am checking the url and differentiating. Based upon the path change I am loading the component
It is working in other environment but not in firefox
My code:
@HostListener ("window:loadurl", ["$event"])
onLoadUrl (event) {

    try {
    let path = event.target.location.href;
    Splitting and getting the path here
    if(path[1].includes("/address")){
    Load address component 
    }
    if(path[1].includes("/marks")){
    Load marks component 
    }
    
}

But it's working fine in chrome and edge but not in firefox

Could you try the load event instead?
@HostListener ("window:load", ["$event"]) // <- changed here
onLoadUrl (event) { 

    try {
    let path = event.target.location.href;
    Splitting and getting the path here
    if(path[1].includes("/address")){
    Load address component 
    }
    if(path[1].includes("/marks")){
    Load marks component 
    }
    
}


using popstate event , what's the purpose of that

@Vishnu you can access the url using this.router.url and perform the same logic, we can even do this on ngOnInit
